# Updating Class veriables

Tags: python, class, variables

(Apologies if the title need rewording)
If I write a class in Python, for example:

```
class Person():
   y = 0
   x = y
```

and I then execute :

```
>>> person = Person()
>>> person.y = 10
>>> person.x
0
```

How do I get `person.x` to automatically update (as it was originally as defined `x = y`)?

Comment: First things first, value assignment has to be done "each time", there's no way to "link" two variables directly. That said, if you just one both of them to have the same value, why not have just one variable with the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question somehow contradicts itself. It seems you want to update class variables but you access it like an instance variable.

So, maybe this is what you want, using instance variables:

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self):
        self.y = 0

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.y


person = Person()
person.y = 10
print(person.x)
```

For class variables, it's slightly more difficult, because Python does not have static properties by default, so you need to define a Metaclass first.

```
class MetaPerson(type):
    y = 0

    def _get(self):
        return self.y

    def _set(self, value):
        raise AttributeError("you can't set x, only y")

    x = property(_get, _set)


class Person(metaclass=MetaPerson):
    pass


Person.y = 10
print(Person.x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make `x` a [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) that just returns `y`. However, I'm not sure why you would use this on a class attribute, so I've decided to ignore that aspect.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.y = 0

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.y

person = Person()
print(person.x)  # -> 0
person.y = 10
print(person.x)  # -> 10
```

Note that I made it a read-only alias on purpose.

```
person.x = 20  # -> AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

But if you want to allow setting `y` via `x`, you could add a setter method:

```
...
    @x.setter
    def x(self, new_value):
        self.y = new_value

person.x = 20
print(person.x, person.y)  # -> 20 20
```

Comment: what does the setter method do? is it better/worse than the property method?

Comment: @Adrian Oh, it's not an alternative, it's an addition to the property that allows you to set `x`.